# List a table by 2 columns that are equal sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
Table: reservations
|  name   |  phone_nr  | progam | #invited_people | invitedby |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Dustin  |  5555555   |   1    |        3        |   NULL    |
|   Joe   |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |  Dustin   |
|   Mary  |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |  Dustin   |
|  Tylor  |   444555   |   1    |        1        |   NULL    |
|   Cody  |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |   Tylor   |
|  Martin |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |  Dustin   |
```

I would like to sort the results after the person who made the reservation (`invitedby == NULL`)
The person who made the invitation should stay at the top and the people who were invited by this person should follow.

Desired output:

```
Table: reservations
|  name   |  phone_nr  | progam | #invited_people | invitedby |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Dustin  |  5555555   |   1    |        3        |   NULL    |
|   Joe   |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |  Dustin   |
|   Mary  |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |  Dustin   |
|  Martin |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |  Dustin   |
|  Tylor  |   444555   |   1    |        1        |   NULL    |
|   Cody  |   NULL     |   1    |        0        |   Tylor   |
```

I'm not that good at SQL.. I've tried to `GROUP BY` the "name" and "invitedby" columns, but it didn't work. Thank you for your help!

Create and Insert statements:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations (
    `name` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    `phone_nr` varchar(30),
    `program` int NOT NULL,
    `#invited_people` int NOT NULL,
    `invitedby` varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO reservations (name, phone_nr, program, `#invited_people`, invitedby) VALUES ('Dustin', '5555555', 1, 3, NULL), ('Joe', NULL, 1, 0, 'Dustin'), ('Mary', NULL, 1, 0, 'Dustin'), ('Tylor', 444555, 1, 1, NULL), ('Cody', NULL, 1, 0, 'Tylor'), ('Martin', NULL, 1, 0, 'Dustin')
```

Query that I've tried (and did not work):
`SELECT * FROM reservation GROUP BY name,invitedby`

PS: I'm using MariaDB with XAMPP on my local machine.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "I've tried to `GROUP BY`"  Where???  We don't see a query.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, I should've read the rules first, my bad :(

Comment: @Eric I'll put the SQL Query up in a minute

Comment: It's totally cool. The only 'bad' is not fixing the issue once you're aware of it.

Comment: @Strawberry There. Now it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order by`:

```
order by coalesce(invitedby, name),   -- groups the inviter and invitees together
         (invitedby is null) desc,    -- puts the inviter first
         name                         -- orders the rest by name
```